What are some "non-visual" tests that could tell me that my MC simulation is running properly?
Suppose I have developed a Monte Carlo simulation program of Argon particles using the LJ potential function.
What are some non-visual tests that could tell me that my MC simulation program is running properly?

Are you concerned with 1. whether it is running? 2. whether it is converging? 3. whether it is converging to the right thing? 1 and 2 have some heuristics but 3 requires some sort of domain-specific comparison to verify.

@whpowell96, 3. whether it is converging to the right thing? --- according to the supplied initial parameters.

Are you sure you are talking about "MC"=MonteCarlo Simulation, or MD= Molecular Dynamics simulation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_dynamics)? I am unaware of how to simulate a gas via a MC method.

Check the properties of the gas against the ideal gas equation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law
You could measure the pressure while increasing temperature, or any other combination in that equation.
Since you do not simulate hard particles and use the LJ potential, you will not find a perfect match, but with argon you should be close enough to an ideal gas. That could give you an idea if something is going wrong or not.
